# Lexical analysis: Comments at end of line

Tags: c#, regex, lexical-analysis

I am tokenizing a string such as:

> BAS=W34 N29 E24 S29$FOP=E6 S6 W6 N6$. A Comment

The period is the "end of command" character, not a "beginning of comment" character.  How can I add a regular expression rule to the lexer such that the period is a token unto itself, but anything after the period is a token with type COMMENT?  I tried `/\..+$/`, but that includes the period in the comment.

Comment: What program are you using?

Comment: How about not period `(?<=[.])[^.]+$`

Comment: I wrote the lexer myself in C#, it uses .NET regular expressions.  It is a lot like http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drew/archive/2009/12/31/a-simple-lexer-in-c-that-uses-regular-expressions.aspx (see Implemention section)

Comment: This will do the job: `(?<=\.).+`

Comment: Using a capturing group would be more efficient, but I am not sure if you can do it with your lexer. E.g. [`^[^.]*\.\s*([^.]*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/bA1mT6/1). It is much easier without regex in C#: `s.Split('.')[1].Trim()`.

Comment: @stribizhev Guess my lexer can't do it, because that returned my entire string.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Thanks, that did it.

Comment: Then your lexer will not be effecient. I would add a group extraction if I were in your shoes. It takes `(?<=\.).+$` 79 steps to match the string, and it takes just 9 steps for my above regex to get it. Look-behinds are costly.

Comment: I wonder why ny question has been downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might could try 2 ways, a non-capturing group, or a look-behind (which is also non-capturing):

```
(?:\.).+$

(?<=\.).+$
```

Comment: The first pattern will include the period in the match (and therefore it will consume it). The second one is fine.

Comment: A look-behind is not only non-capturing, it is non-consuming. A non-capturing group is "consuming" characters.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer without knowing the actual tools involved, but consider inverting the logic: use a regex such as `/^.+\./` to detect a command, and everything after is a COMMENT.